# How to call removeEventLisener when addEventListener in a method and removeEventListener in a global function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, event-handling

There are plenty of questions and answers on a similar topic, but I feel that this is a slightly different question that the other question's answers did not quite answer this. I have a constructor, and its prototype has an addEventListener, is called with a global function, `once`. Once needs to be global, but the addEventListener needs to be in the prototype's method. How would I remove the event listener, would I put `once.bind(that)` in or `once` for the function in removeEventListener?

```
var once = function(event) {
  removeEventListener("keydown", /*something*/);
}
Chomp.prototype.playerMove = function() {
  var that = this;
  addEventListener("keydown", once.bind(that)); 
}
```

Thanks ahead of time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "non-strict" mode you could use `arguments.callee` to obtain a reference to the function `once`, as bound by `once.bind(that)`.  Unfortunately in ES5 strict mode that functionality has been removed.

You could call a separate function (which must be named, so it can be passed to `removeEventListener`) that handles the unbinding of the event handler.

```
Chomp.prototype.playerMove = function() {
    var that = this;
    var local_once = function() {
        removeEventListener('keydown', local_once);  // deregister this function
        return once.apply(that, arguments);          // invoke global "once"
    }
    addEventListener('keydown', local_once);
}
```

[too late - I just realised this does of course require modifying `once`, but there's no other means of referencing the function generated by your `once.bind(that)` unless it's stored somewhere that your original `once` can get at it.  This solution keeps the "only call this once" logic local to `.playerMove`].

Answer (score 1):

Try this updated code:

```
var once = function(event) {
   document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", once);
```

}

```
Chomp.prototype.playerMove = function() {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", once); 
}
```

You can't use `once.bind(that)` in the `once` function. `That` isn't known in the function once. And every eventlistener with a bind in it, can only be removed with the exact function call as how it was set. If you would refer to `once.bind(this)` in the remove function, it would be a different wrapper than in the add function and will not remove the event. The code above attaches the EventListener to the `body` and removes it when the users pushes a key.

Another option (nicer) is to save the binded function onto the player

```
var once = function(event) {
   document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownEvent);
```

}

```
Chomp.prototype.playerMove = function() {
    this.keyDownEvent = once.bind(this);
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownEvent); 
}
```